# Inverting FN keys

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts

My notebook is equipped with one of those fancy multimedia keyboards where you have to hold the FN key in order to use the classic function keys (F1-F12).

Is it possible to invert this behaviour in Unity/Gnome/X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on an HP laptop. Drove me nuts for a while, until I saw the option to switch it's behavior in the BIOS. You might want to check yours.

Answer (score 4):

If BIOS suggestion from [Migs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227034/inverting-fn-keys#comment385849_227034) doesn't work, you may consider this solution.

First, you need to check what keysyms values is your keyboard sending. For this, use `xev`.

After that, read about `xmodmap`. This is the tool that allows you to create custom keymaps, and alter how keys are interpreted.

Now it will make you feel stupid, but you need to rebind all media keys to corresponding F keys, and vice-versa. This way, whenever you'd press F1 it will be interpreted like(let's say) "Play", and whenever you press Play - it will be considered F1.

It's not a perfect nor most elegant solution, but it will work.